# Problems with mode-line displaying

Tags: emacs

I am using this as my mode-line in emacs, but
     `'(:eval (last-dir default-directory))`
is showing this in the message buffer
    `Error during redisplay: (eval (last-dir default-directory)) signaled (void-function last-dir) [594 times]`
How can I get it working properly please? and how can I put in the file size to the mode-line?

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
 (list
   " "
   mode-line-buffer-identification
   " │ "
   "dir: "
   '(:eval (last-dir default-directory))
    " │ "
   ;; '%02' to set to 2 chars at least; prevents flickering
    "%04l"
     ","
     "%02c"
     " │ "
   '(:eval (format-time-string "%H:%M"))
     " | "
   '(:eval (if (buffer-modified-p) "M" "-"))
   '(:eval (if buffer-read-only    "R" "-"))
   '(:eval (if (window-dedicated-p (selected-window)) "D" "-"))
   " │ "
   mode-line-modes
    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `last-dir` is indeed not defined.  Is it meant to extract the last component of the directory name?  If so, you could use this instead:

```
(:eval (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name default-directory)))
```

<del>You could add the file size with the `buffer-size` function: `(:eval (format "%d" (buffer-size)))`</del>

To include the buffer size in the mode line, use `%I` as described in [Iqbal Ansari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21948891/113848).

Comment: Thanks, its half-way there, once I'd put a ' in front of each (:eval, but the buffer size comes over as four digits, how can they be shown as 'kb' or even 'mb' please?

Answer (score 1):

To display the buffer size (in terms of KB or MB) you add "%I" to your mode-line format. From the documentation

> %i -- print the size of the buffer.
>
> %I -- like %i, but use k, M, G, etc., to abbreviate.

So to get mode-line with name of directory and buffer size you can do

```
(setq mode-line-format '((:eval (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name default-directory))) ", file is of size %I"))
```

I recommend that you read the documentation of mode-line-format, do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`mode-line-format`<kbd>RET</kbd> which explains the various options available for formatting the mode-line.